# Trying to Normalize tables to 2NF and 3NF

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf

I have this dependency diagram I'm trying to make into 2NF and then 3NF. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

Here's the dependency:[image]

This is how I tried to model it:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the diagram correctly, your "1b" is the right decomposition. All the tables in "1b" are in at least 5NF, though.

The notion that you can normalize to 2NF *and no higher*, or to 3NF *and no higher*, is a common misunderstanding of how normalization works. It's quite common to start with a relation that's in 1NF, and in a single step end up with all the relations in 5NF.